How to order rows by specifying column names, not indices?
I am working on a Shiny app, using the datatable package. I am displaying a table with DT::datatable() and I want to use its order option to specify an initial ordering of the rows of the table. The help I could find here tells me I can use some syntax like order = list(list(2, 'asc'), list(4, 'desc')) to order using first ascending order of column 2 and then descending order of column 4, but instead of using column indices, I want to use column names. If I were using the underlying DataTables library in JavaScript, it seems I would be able to do just that: see here.
Question: What is the appropriate syntax for me to write such an sorting specification inside a Shiny app, within the order() option of DT::datatable()? I tried stuff like list(list(name = "animalID", dir = "asc"), list(4, "desc")), to no avail.
My goal here is to find a direct translation of the syntax regarding using names in DT's original options so that we can update section 4.1 of the manpage on using DT in Shiny. I know how to sort a table on columns specified by their names in the general context of R programming.

DT[order(animalID, -fourth_variable_name)] ?

If @Edward's suggestion doesn't work, take a two-stage approach: construct a vector of column names and then interrogate it to obtain the index of the column name.  You can then use the index in your DT settings.

I agree with Limey; find out what position your column names are, and construct the ordering command from that.

Thank you @Edward, @Limey and @Nir Graham, but it seems you overlooked the fact I am writing R code, not JS. This is the whole call I am attempting to write:
d %>% DT::datatable(extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedHeader'), options = list(dom = 'lBfrtip', order = list(list(name = "animalID", dir = "asc"), list(2, "desc"))))

What has this to do with JS? You have a dataframe in R which is passed to DT::datatable and beforehand, as suggested above, you can obtain the indices of the columns and pass them then to the options. Also it would be good to have a minimal example of your current progress and not only code fragments.

@jaybee it seems YOU have overlooked that nothing in their responses has to do with JS.

@LTyrone The (second) duplicate vote is wrong in my opinion, the question here is about DT, whereas the linked question is about data.table.

@Jan - thanks for that. I'd  selected the wrong link in error and had not noticed.

Thank you all, let me clarify a few things. First, @Jan is right. I am not using the data.table class, but the DT one. Second: I know perfectly well how to sort a table (using names or indices) in R, before piping into DT::datatable(). No problem there. My hope was to get a direct translation of the syntax we have here regarding using names: https://datatables.net/reference/option/order so that we can update section 4.1 here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html.

As highlighted in the comments, you need a way to translate names to positions. Here's one way how to do that:
library(DT)

my_data <- iris

## define your desired order: names are the columns according to which you want to sort
## and the values describe whether you want to sort ascending or descending
desired_order <- c(Petal.Width = "desc", Sepal.Width = "asc")

idx <- match(names(desired_order), names(my_data)) |>
  mapply(\(i, o) list(i, o), i = _, o = desired_order, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

str(idx)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : int 4
#   ..$ : chr "desc"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : int 2
#   ..$ : chr "asc"


datatable(my_data, options = list(order = idx))


Thanks @thothal, looks like an elaborate but 100% efficient solution. I have added a clarifying comment above, as my hope was to get a direct translation of the original DT options syntax into the R syntax of DT::datatable(...., options = .....)). But let me try your solution, in the meantime.

could oyu please explain the non-standard (at least for the average R user) parts of your syntax, namely \(i, o) and i = _? I read somewhere that until R version 1.8.0 (!), the underscore was yet another form of the assignment operator, but surely that is by times long gone?

This is a new-ish feature added to R as of version 4.1.0(IIRC). The \(x) syntax defines an anonymous function and is equivalent to function(x) but shorter. _ is a placeholder which works together with the pipe operator |> and basically says the left hand side of the pipe should be inserted at this position. Thus, x |> f(1, b = _) is the same as f(1, b = x). Unlike magrittr's %>% pipe, the placeholder works onyl with named arguments. You want to read help("|>") and help("function").

Great explanation, thanks @thothal! IMHO, a weird and unexplainable move to abandon the older . in favour of the newer _ to indicate the place where to inject the LHS of a piping operation. How is that any more intuitive for R users, especially when we already have things like the .x in anonymous functions introduced by ~?

Well, . and ~ are tidyverse syntax. |> and _ are base R. The latter is said to be more performant (as it is not an extra call but a syntax transformation), but does not allow for the same flexibility as tidyverse syntax. You do not need an additional library, so in the end it is up 2 the user which paradigm to follow.
